# XSL FO Tables with exceptions

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have a problem with a .XSL file, I need to make a table with this values, but with my file I do a table without columns, and I would like to have them, a column with the data of "año" and another with the data of "titulo" . I don't know how to do it. This is my code:

```
<xsl:template match="catalogo">
<fo:table border="solid" border-collapse="collapse" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
  <fo:table-body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
      <xsl:if test="año &gt; 2000">
      <fo:block color="green">
      <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
      </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="año &lt; 2000">
      <fo:block color="red">
      <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
      </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="año='2000'">
      <fo:block color="black">
      <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
      </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>

      <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="año"/>
      </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result of this is:

[image]

Comment: The input XML file is needed to create a [mcve]. Please add it via an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60998285/edit) to the question in a `code` section.

Comment: Look at your code in detail .... you create an fo:table-row, great.
How many fo:table-cell's are in that row? You code shows one.
Yet the question seems to imply you what two columns?
you only create one, you get one.

Answer (score 0):

Who knows what you want, but as a total guess:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
  <fo:table-row>
    <!-- add a table cell for ano -->
    <fo:table-cell>
       <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="año"/></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black">
      <xsl:if test="año &gt; 2000">
      <fo:block color="green">
      <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
      </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="año &lt; 2000">
      <fo:block color="red">
      <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
      </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="año='2000'">
      <fo:block color="black">
      <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
      </fo:block>
      </xsl:if>

      <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="año"/>
      </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but you could simplify your `color` selection as:

```
<fo:block>
  <xsl:attribute name="color">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="año &gt; 2000">green</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="año &lt; 2000">red</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>black</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="titulo"/>
</fo:block>
```

It could be even shorter if we knew that you were using either XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0.